# How can I show several different divs in the same popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**The screen i'm trying to make;**

[image]

**The screen I can do;**

[image]

As can be seen from the pictures; The divs in the 2nd picture are separate from each other. I'm trying to do as in the 1st picture, but I couldn't. I want to show the incoming data in the same popup.

**html**

```
<div className="installmentinfo__container">
  {
    props.installmentList?.map((e, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="installmentinfo">
          <div className="column">
            <div className="installmentnumber" >{(i + 1).toString()}</div>
            <div className="installmentdate">{e.date}</div>
            <div className="installmentamount">{e.amount} {e.currency}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
</div>
```

**css**

```
.installmentinfo__container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 340px;

  .installmentinfo {
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: auto;
    border: var(--border);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;

    .column {
      display: flex;
      margin: 5px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      border-bottom: 1.5px solid #d1d1d1;
    }

    .installmentnumber {
      float: left;
    }

    .installmentdate {
      width: 50%;
      color: black !important;
    }

    .installmentamount {
      width: 50%;
      color: black !important;
      font-weight: 1000;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: I'm guessing this is React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
.installmentinfo__container{
   border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
   border-radius: 10px;
   width: 320px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #d1d1d1;

  .installmentinfo {
       background-color: white;
       width: 280px;
       height: auto;
       border: var(--border);
       border-radius: 0.5em;
       padding: 0.5em 1em;

   .column {
      display: flex;
      margin: 5px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      border-bottom: 1.5px solid #d1d1d1;
    }

    .installmentnumber {
       float: left;
    }

    .installmentdate {
       width: 50%;
       color: black !important;
    }

    .installmentamount {
       width: 50%;
       color: black !important;
       font-weight: 1000;
    }
  }
}
```